# NodeJS Mysql Stop Server Crash on Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, locomotivejs

I am using https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
and everytime a mysql query throw an error, for example if a row does not exist. The node server crashes.

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from table1 where id = 2',  function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  if (rows[0]) { 
    console.log('The result is  ', rows[0].user);
  }
});
connection.end();
```

How do I simply print the errors to the page rather than crash the server.

Answer (score 1):

If an error occurs, your code `console.log`'s it but tries to access `rows[0]` anyway. In case of errors `rows` will be undefined so `rows[0]` will trigger a new error.

Easily fixed with an `else` in combination with a length check:

```
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
} else if (rows.length) { 
  console.log('The result is  ', rows[0].user);
} else {
  console.log("Query didn't return any results.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `return` statement:

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from table1 where id = 2',  function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  if (rows[0]) { 
    console.log('The result is  ', rows[0].user);
  }
});
connection.end();
```

This is cleaner IMO and guarantees that I wont leave anything out of an if statement block where it shouldn't.